# Strip email address suffix

Tags: xml, email, xslt

I have an xml as follows:

```
<bug>
    <reporter name="Jane Doe">jane.doe@example.com</reporter>
    <assigned_to name="John Doe">john.doe@example.com</assigned_to>
    <who name="john Doe">john.doe@example.com</who>
</bug>
```

I would like to output jane.doe, john.doe by removing '@example.com' off the string.  I am new to xsl and am limited to xsl 1.0.  Is this possible?

Comment: xml is invalid: </bug> end element is incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the xpath function **[substring-before](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before)**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before('jane-doe@example.com', '@')"/>
```

[Working example](http://xsltransform.net/948Fn57)